# Package organization in sub folder

Tags: go

I am trying to make some package to push on github.

I have the following structure

```
mypkg/
------main.go
------go.mod
-----/models
------------/fluids
------------/compress/compress.go
------------/std/std.go
```

Well I just want to put just go file direct on models/fluids without sub folder, I mean:

```
------------/fluids
------------/fluids/compress.go
------------/fluids/std.go
```

but when importing from mail file I get

```
found packages compress (compress.go) and std (std.go) in ***/mypkg/models/fluid.
```

Is any way to avoid creating so many subfolders?

Comment: Nobody is ever going to force you to create subfolders. But each folder in a Go project must contain at most one package. You have two packages in the same folder, which is causing your problem. Your choices are: 1) Make them the same package. 2) Put them in separate folders. There's no other option.

Comment: Ok, thanks. i will put the whole code in the same file maybe

Comment: Nobody said it needs to be in the same file. Two files is perfectly acceptable. They just need to be part of the same package.

Answer (score 0):

To illustrate [Flimzy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13860/flimzy) comment, if you are moving `std.go` and `compress.go` in the `fluids` folder, you need to change the first line in both those files in order to see:

```
package fluids
```

(or any other name you want, as long as you are using the same package name in any files in that fluids folder)

As explained in "[Package names](https://blog.golang.org/package-names)":

> Build tools map package paths onto directories.
> There is no actual relationship among the packages in one of these directories; a directory just provides a way to arrange the files.
> Any package can import any other package provided the import does not create a cycle.